# How could I delay the shutdown till all channels(spring-integration) are empty?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a spring boot application that loads files into a QueueChannel. From there an async ServiceActivator processes the file messages.

On application stop the shutdown should wait till all queued messages are processed.

application.properties:
server.shutdown: graceful

spring-integration version: 6.0.2

I tried the following solutions:

```
MessageChannels.queue("inputChannel", 20)
            .gracefulShutdownTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60)) // wait up to 60 seconds for in-flight messages to be processed on this channel
            .get();
```

-> Not supported in spring-integration 6

```
 IntegrationFlowContextInitializer initializer = new IntegrationFlowContextInitializer();
    initializer.setShutdownTimeout(30000); // default timeout for all channels is 30 seconds
    return initializer;
```

-> Not supported in spring-integration 6

```
@Bean
public GracefulShutdownStrategy gracefulShutdownStrategy() {
    return new DefaultGracefulShutdownStrategy()
            .shutdownTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30)); // default timeout for all channels is 30 seconds
}
```

-> Not supported in spring-integration 6

```
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(40);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
```

-> Did not do the trick

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a feature yet in Spring Integration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/7095.

I would suggest to use a persistent store for a `QueueChannel` to not lose messages between restarts. Although it is not clear why would one load files into a queue if you simply could go ahead and process them immediately after load.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#message-store

Comment: With the queue I limit the amount of files coming from the FileReadingMessageSource. Maybe there is an easier way and using DirectChannel. But also there you have to make sure all files are processed on shutdown.

Comment: With a `DirectChannel` there is no extra data in the memory, so whatever was polled at the moment is going to be processed on shutdown.

Comment: My ServiceActivators work asynchonously. How could I limit the files on input so that I just have e.g. 10 in the application concurrently?

Comment: An `ExecutorChannel`. Although, if you say that your service is already an async, I'm not sure why you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution over a servlet listener:

```
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> myServletListener() {
    ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> srb = new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>();
    srb.setListener(new ExampleServletContextListener());
    return srb;
}
```

in the contextDestroyed method I can check the QueueChannels if they are empty otherwise give it some time.

I would have thought that the graceful shutdown would give you some kind of support for such use cases.